# How to remove duplicate values of a group in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle SQL, i would like to remove/hide duplicate values.

Actual:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |

Expected:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
|  | b |
| 2 | c |
|  | d |
|  | e |
| 3 | f |

Please help on the approaches.

Comment: Don't do this! Rather than it, use reporting tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use lag analytic function like below. Make sure the third parameter for lag function is obviously different from the first parameter for the first line in each partition group. I chose "-1 * t.Column_1", but you could simply use a literal like 999999999.

```sql
With test_t (Column_1,  Column_2) as (
select 1,   'a' from dual union all
select 1,   'b' from dual union all
select 2,   'c' from dual union all
select 2,   'd' from dual union all
select 2,   'e' from dual union all
select 3,   'f' from dual
)
select 
  case 
    when lag(t.Column_1, 1, -1 * t.Column_1) over(partition by t.Column_1 order by t.Column_2) != t.Column_1 
        then Column_1 
    else null
  end Column_1
, Column_2
from test_t t
order by t.Column_1, t.Column_2
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In SQL*Plus, that's simple:

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test order by col1, col2;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----
         1 a
         1 b
         2 c
         2 d
         2 e
         3 f

6 rows selected.
```

**BREAK** on desired column:

```
SQL> break on col1
SQL>
SQL> select * from test order by col1, col2;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----
         1 a
           b
         2 c
           d
           e
         3 f

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Any decent reporting tool (Apex, Oracle Reports Builder, ...) have an option to *break* the report. Depending on what you really use, "solution" might differ.

Comment: Thanks, but i have more no of records to perform this substitution via SQL developer.